# Fill SPAN with SELECT value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still fresh to jQuery. Maybe someone could point me in the right direction with my problem.

I have multiple LI item. Every one of them holds two SELECT items. When I hit a button I want to display two SPANS. Each of them holds the value of one of the the SELECTS.

I get it to work with one LI. But not with more. I tried the each function, but can't get it to work.

Can someone help me please?

```
    $("##triggerButton").click(function() {
            $("li").each(function(){
                var firstSelect = $('##Folder_ID').find(":selected").text();
                var secondSelect = $('##Type_ID').find(":selected").text();

                $('##folder-view').text(firstSelect);                
                $('##type-view').text(secondSelect);  
              });
    });
```

Comment: Why do you need two hashtag `#` in your selector? It seems invalid selector.

Comment: can you share the relevant html as well

Comment: From your question, you have duplicate IDs whereas IDs need to be unique in the document tree. Why don't you change them to classes if you are in control of the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Without your HTML code, i think you are using double ID's and your select looks like `<select id="#folder-view">`. Try this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.each($("#wrapper-of-selections .selection"), function() {
      $("#result").append(
        "<span>"
        + $("option:selected", this).val() + ": " + $("option:selected", this).text()
        + "</span><br/>"
      );
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="wrapper-of-selections">
  <li>
    <select class="selection">
      <option value="v11">Value 11</option>
      <option value="v21">Value 21</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select class="selection">
      <option value="v12">Value 12</option>
      <option value="v22">Value 22</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
<button>Click ME</button>
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
```